# React - filtering array by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have prepared some array filtering functionality:

```
export default function App() {
  const input = [
    {"unix":1, "val_1":"True", "val_2": 5, "val_3": 10},
    {"unix":2, "val_1":"True", "val_2": 5, "val_3": 10},
    {"unix":3, "val_1":"False", "val_2": 3, "val_3": 2},
    {"unix":4, "val_1":"True", "val_2": 7, "val_3": 1},
    {"unix":5, "val_1":"True", "val_2": 7, "val_3": 1},
  ]
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        [...new Map(input.map(i => [i.val_1+i.val_2+i.val3, i])).values()].map(
          (data) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <p>unix: {data.unix} val_1: {data.val_1} val_2: {data.val_2} val_3: {data.val_3}</p>
                <p>-----------------------</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's filtering this array by val_1, but how to filter by val_1, val_2 and val_3?

Some simple solution is just concatenate val_2, val_2 and val_3:

```
[...new Map(input.map(i => [i.val_1+i.val_2+i.val_3, i])).values()].map( ... )
```

But I'm not sure it's a good idea.

What do you think?

Edit:
If filtered by val_1, val_2 and val_3 expected output:

```
unix: 2 val_1: True val_2: 5 val_3: 10

-----------------------

unix: 3 val_1: False val_2: 3 val_3: 2

-----------------------

unix: 5 val_1: True val_2: 7 val_3: 1

-----------------------
```

Comment: You must be mistaking[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: what is it that you want to do? what output do you `expect`?

Comment: @CrispenGari , I did add the expected output.

Comment: @CrispenGari Please don't use code formatting for emphasis; use **bold** (`**bold**`) or _italics_ (`_italics_`) for emphasis. Leave code formatting for, well, code.

Comment: What conditions are you filtering based on?

Comment: @CrispenGari just want to have only one row from list above when val_1, val_2 and val_3 are the same. I mean:
if val_1[idx] == val_1[idx+1] && val_3[idx] == val_3[idx+1]  && val_3[idx] == val_3[idx+1] just show row[idx]

Comment: Concatenation is unlikely to work well, because "231" can be the concatenation of "2" and "31" or "23" and "1" or "231" and "" or "" and "231" (I don't know enough about your dataset to know if any of those combinations are possible, but nonetheless, it's a problem in the general sense.

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove duplicates...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**You should specify which key are you filtering based on** for example  if you want to return iterms based on the following conditions:

```js
unix > 2 and item.val_1 === True
```

**Then you can do it as follows:**

```js
filtered = input.filter(item => item.unix > 2 && item.val_1)
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Yeah, but how to compare the item[idx].val_1 and item[idx+1].val_1?
And show just and item[idx] if item[idx].val_1 == item[idx+1].val_1?

Comment: `item[idx+1]` is not iteratable if you use filter in  your case. You can not do that